# How to create PDF files in Python

Tags: python, pdf

I'm working on a project which takes some images from user and then creates a PDF file which contains all of these images.

Is there any way or any tool to do this in Python? E.g. to create a PDF file (or eps, ps) from image1 + image 2 + image 3 -> PDF file?

Comment: When in doubt, prefix whatever you are searching for by `py` ;-)

Comment: Another SO search trick: `[language or tag] some_keyword`  as in `[python] PDF` or `[python] PDF image`

Comment: For those coming here using matplolib: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788685/python-saving-multiple-figures-into-one-pdf-file

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I suggest [pyPdf](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2). It works really nice. I also wrote a blog post some while ago, you can find it [here](http://ssscripting.wordpress.com/2009/08/16/get-your-job-done-faster-with-pypdf/).

Comment: A current fork of PyPDF2 is located [here](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2).

Comment: Note that pypdf only cuts/pastes/etc.. existing pdf content - you can't add text or images to a pdf.

Comment: pyPDF2 is not for creating new PDF documents, 4cs

Comment: You can check [pdfme](https://github.com/aFelipeSP/pdfme) library. It's the most powerful library in python to create PDF documents.

Answer (score 183):

Here is my experience after following the hints on this page.

1. pyPDF can't embed images into files. It can only split and merge. (Source: Ctrl+F through its [documentation page](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/pythondoc-pyPdf.pdf.html))
   Which is great, but not if you have images that are not already embedded in a PDF.
2. [pyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2) doesn't seem to have any extra documentation on top of pyPDF.
3. ReportLab is very extensive. ([Userguide](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf)) However, with a bit of Ctrl+F and grepping through its source, I got this:

   - First, [download the Windows installer](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/download/) and [source](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab)
   - Then try this on Python command line:

     ```
     from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
     from reportlab.lib.units import inch, cm
     c = canvas.Canvas('ex.pdf')
     c.drawImage('ar.jpg', 0, 0, 10*cm, 10*cm)
     c.showPage()
     c.save()
     ```

All I needed is to get a bunch of images into a PDF, so that I can check how they look and print them. The above is sufficient to achieve that goal.

ReportLab is great, but would benefit from including helloworlds like the above prominently in its documentation.

Comment: I must say reportlab is the best for PDF generation that I have tried, definitely the most complete. However, it's also a bit more complicated.
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/21/reportlab-tables-creating-tables-in-pdfs-with-python/

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @JoseSalvatierra Thanks Jose...this is really easy. Thanks for the blog link.

Comment: PyPDF2 documentation: https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - you might want to update your answer :-)

Comment: If you are looking for a way to combine the power of Python and LaTeX for automated PDF generation, please see https://intuitivetutorial.com/2020/11/08/automated-pdf-creation/

Answer (score 42):

I suggest [Pdfkit](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit). (installation [guide](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/))

It creates pdf from html files. I chose it to create pdf in 2 steps from my Python Pyramid stack:

1. Rendering server-side with mako templates with the style and markup you want for you pdf document
2. Executing `pdfkit.from_string(...)` method by passing the rendered html as parameter

This way you get a pdf document with styling and images supported.

You can install it as follows :

- using pip

  `pip install pdfkit`
- You will also need to install wkhtmltopdf ([on Ubuntu](http://fedir.github.io/web/blog/2013/09/25/install-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu/)).

Comment: From a unit test perspective this methodology seems superior as it allows for unit testing of the html (what is expected to be seen). Not sure if that is within the scope of the OP, but it is a good note.

Answer (score 15):

fpdf works well for me. Much simpler than ReportLab and really free. Works with UTF-8.

Comment: Link/Descrip.: http://www.fpdf.org/ FPDF is a PHP class which allows to generate PDF files with pure PHP, that is to say without using the PDFlib library. F from FPDF stands for Free: you may use it for any kind of usage and modify it to suit your needs.  FPDF has other advantages: high level functions. Here is a list of its main features: Choice of measure unit, page format and margins,  Page header and footer management,  Automatic page break,   Automatic line break and text justify,   Image support (JPEG, PNG and GIF),  Colors, Links, TrueType, Type1 and encoding support, Page compression

Comment: Not very relevant considering the question was about Python, not PHP

Comment: why all this downvoting ? fpdf is available also for python. pip install fpdf works

Comment: fpdf might have started with php. But [there is a python](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial/index.html) port which works really well. So I thinks this is a very relevant answer which deserve more up votes than down votes. (I am not sure about the situation when this answer was initially posted)

Answer (score 14):

You can try [this](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Python-for-PDF-Generation/)(Python-for-PDF-Generation) or you can try [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/news), which has support for printing to pdf.

**Python for PDF Generation**
The Portable Document Format (PDF) lets you create documents that look exactly the same on every platform. Sometimes a PDF document needs to be generated dynamically, however, and that can be quite a challenge. Fortunately, there are libraries that can help. This article examines one of those for Python.

Read more at http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Python-for-PDF-Generation/#whoCFCPh3TAks368.99

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution that works with only the standard packages. `matplotlib` has a PDF backend to save figures to PDF. You can create a figures with subplots, where each subplot is one of your images. You have full freedom to mess with the figure: Adding titles, play with position, etc. Once your figure is done, save to PDF. Each call to `savefig` will create another page of PDF.

Example below plots 2 images side-by-side, on page 1 and page 2.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imread
import os
import numpy as np

files = [ "Column0_Line16.jpg", "Column0_Line47.jpg" ]
def plotImage(f):
    folder = "C:/temp/"
    im = imread(os.path.join(folder, f)).astype(np.float32) / 255
    plt.imshow(im)
    a = plt.gca()
    a.get_xaxis().set_visible(False) # We don't need axis ticks
    a.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

pp = PdfPages("c:/temp/page1.pdf")
plt.subplot(121)
plotImage(files[0])
plt.subplot(122)
plotImage(files[1])
pp.savefig(plt.gcf()) # This generates page 1
pp.savefig(plt.gcf()) # This generates page 2
pp.close()
```

Comment: in my test, the code generates single page with 2 images

Comment: updated version of the code can be found in https://github.com/constructor-igor/TechSugar/blob/master/pythonSamples/tips/pdf-writer.py

Answer (score 10):

[rinohtype](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/) supports embedding PDF, PNG and JPEG images (natively) and other bitmap formats (when Pillow is installed).

(Full disclosure: I am the author of rinohtype)

Comment: Hey! Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that it's quite powerfull tool and unlike many, many others listed here is not a python wrapper for an acient php/ruby/perl/pyqt4/other crap library.

Comment: Do you have some examples of things that have been generated with this? Is it general-purpose or really only made for technical manuals? Can it be used for business reporting, for example?

Comment: @wordsforthewise For now just the rinohtype PDF manuals linked from the sidebar at http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/. It's mainly aimed at flowing a stream of content onto pages (versus placing text/images at specific coordinates). I guess business reporting falls under that use case?

Answer (score 8):

fpdf is python (too). And often used. See PyPI / pip search. But maybe it was renamed from pyfpdf to fpdf. From features:
PNG, GIF and JPG support (including transparency and alpha channel)

Comment: Your answer is unclear, but thyere's certainly PyFPDF pfoject https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: All the confusion in the naming is a really a pity. This answer and the comment by @WojciechKaczmarek really deserve more upvotes and attention. PyFPDF is a python port of an often used PDF library originally written in PHP.

Answer (score 8):

If you are familiar with LaTex you might want to consider [pylatex](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/)

One of the advantages of pylatex is that it is easy to control the image quality. The images in your pdf will be of the same quality as the original images. When using reportlab, I experienced that the images were automatically compressed, and the image quality reduced.

The disadvantage of pylatex is that, since it is based on LaTex, it can be hard to place images exactly where you want on the page. However, I have found that using the position argument in the Figure class, and sometimes Subfigure, gives good enough results.

Example code for creating a pdf with a single image:

```
from pylatex import Document, Figure

doc = Document(documentclass="article")
with doc.create(Figure(position='p')) as fig:
fig.add_image('Lenna.png')

doc.generate_pdf('test', compiler='latexmk', compiler_args=["-pdf", "-pdflatex=pdflatex"], clean_tex=True)
```

In addition to installing pylatex (pip install pylatex), you need to install LaTex. For Ubuntu and other Debian systems you can run `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`. If you are using Windows I would recommend [MixTex](https://miktex.org/howto/download-miktex)

Answer (score 7):

I have done this quite a bit in PyQt and it works very well.  Qt has extensive support for images, fonts, styles, etc and all of those can be written out to pdf documents.

Comment: Wow, Qt looks amazing. They say they support 15 plaforms, inc. Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, Android, iOS, Windows RT plus these Real-Time Operating Systems-     INTEGRITY   QNX    VxWorks http://www.qt.io/qt-framework/ . And, since I'm  a python fan, I like "PyQt combines all the advantages of Qt and Python. A programmer has all the power of Qt, but is able to exploit it with the simplicity of Python. " http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro

Comment: @AnneTheAgile I can't help myself to comment with "*Qt IS amazing*".

Answer (score 7):

I believe that matplotlib has the ability to serialize graphics, text and other objects to a pdf document.

Comment: Yes, you can. [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12939210/420867) has some good links on how to do it.

Answer (score 7):

I use [rst2pdf](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf) to create a pdf file, since I am more familiar with RST than with HTML. It supports embedding almost any kind of raster or vector images.

It requires [reportlab](https://www.reportlab.com/), but I found reportlab is not so straight forward to use (at least for me).

Answer (score 5):

You can actually try xhtml2pdf http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/68/

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what format your image files are in, but for a project here at work I used the tiff2pdf tool in LibTIFF from [RemoteSensing.org](http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/).
Basically just used subprocess to call tiff2pdf.exe with the appropriate argument to read the kind of tiff I had and output the kind of pdf I wanted.  If they aren't tiffs you could probably convert them to tiffs using PIL, or maybe find a tool more specific to your image type (or more generic if the images will be diverse) like ReportLab mentioned above.