# Python saving multiple figures into one PDF file

Tags: python, matplotlib

In python (for one figure created in a GUI) I was able to save the figure under .jpg and also .pdf by either using:

```
plt.savefig(filename1 +  '.pdf')
```

or

```
plt.savefig(filename1 +  '.jpg')
```

Using one file I would like to save multiple figures in either .pdf or .jpg (just like its done in math lab). Can anybody please help with this?

Comment: A little bit of google foo brought me here: http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/

Comment: Updated link for the comment above (it's now pyPdf2): https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use [`PdfPages`](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_pdf_api.html#matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages) to solve your problem. Pass your `figure` object to the `savefig` method.

For example, if you have a whole pile of `figure` objects open and you want to save them into a multi-page PDF, you might do:

```
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf
pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("output.pdf")
for fig in xrange(1, figure().number): ## will open an empty extra figure :(
    pdf.savefig( fig )
pdf.close()
```

Comment: Worked a treat for me too, however I had to use `xrange(1, figure.number)` as `Figure object is not callable`

Comment: I had to use pyplot.gcf().number, which I recommend you use as it's more widely applicable.

Comment: Also, one thing I forgot to recommend is you should go to pyplot.gcf().number+1

Comment: @jimh Good advice, thank you! Using `plt.gcf().number + 1` (with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, of course) instead of `figure().number` did the job. (I'm on Python 3.5.)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! It helped a lot with some minor modifications. 

One thing to point out is that you cannot edit/append anything to the pdf once it's closed. Any updates will overwrite the original pdf. If you have multiple plots, the suggestion would be to save them in a list/dict and then loop over it when creating the pdf.

Comment: It is best to use the context manger here: `with PdfPages("graphs.pdf") as pdf: pdf.savefig(fig)`

Comment: This worked for me
`for fig in range(1, plt.gcf().number + 1)
        pdf.savefig(fig)
    pdf.close()`

Comment: getting error AttributeError: 'LatexManager' object has no attribute 'latex'

Answer (score 17):

Do you mean save multiple figures *into* one file, or save multiple figures using *one script*?

Here's how you can save two different figures using one *script*.

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> fig1 = plt.figure()
>>> plt.plot(range(10))
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10261bd90>]
>>> fig2 = plt.figure()
>>> plt.plot(range(10,20))
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10263b890>]
>>> fig1.savefig('fig1.png')
>>> fig2.savefig('fig2.png')
```

...which produces these two plots into their own ".png" files: 
[image]

[image]

To save them to the same *file*, use **subplots**:

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> axis1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
>>> axis1.plot(range(10))
>>> axis2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
>>> axis2.plot(range(10,20))
>>> fig.savefig('multipleplots.png')
```

The above script produces this single ".png" file:
[image]

Comment: I think that this should be the accepted answer for it really does what OP was asking for without merging two pdf files using external library.

Comment: This is not a good answer, because the OP is not asking how to plot multiple subplots in the same figure and them save it, nor is he asking how to save to separate files -- presumably that is obvious.  The question is about saving separate figures to the same file.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct however I compiled a more up-to-date solution that you can copy-paste.

```py
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
figs = [fig1, fig2, etc] # list of figures
with PdfPages('output.pdf') as pdf:
    for fig in figs:
        pdf.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight')
```

`bbox_inches='tight'` is to make sure the labels fit in the figure.

The context manager makes sure the pdf file is closed appropriately in case of an exception. And you don't have to close it manually yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue.  I was trying to put 2,000 scatter plots into a single .pdf.  I was able to start the procedure, but it aborted after a few hundred.
Even when I created six scatter charts into one .pdf, the .pdf file was enormous (like 7mb) for just six .jpg's that were 30kb each.  When I opened the .pdf, it appeared that the .pdf was painting every point on the chart (each chart had thousands of points) instead of displaying an image.  Some day, I will figure out the correct options, but here is a quick and dirty work-around.   I printed the scatter plots to individual .jpg files in a local directory.

Comment: this is a good general approach to saving figures, however it doesn't address the question asked! the author already knew how to save individual figures but was wondering how to save multiple figures in one document.