# saving multiple plots to pdf with PdfPages python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdfpages

I'm trying to save my output (70+ graphs) from jyputer notebook into pdf file.
No errors or whatsoever, but only the first graph is being exported.
Can anyone please help me to understand what is wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf

pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("output.pdf")
df_num = df.select_dtypes(include = ['float64', 'int64'])

with PdfPages(r'output.pdf') as export_pdf:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
    for col in df_num.columns:
        hist = df_num[col].hist(bins=10)
        print("Plotting for column {}".format(col))
        plt.title("{}".format(col), fontsize=20) 
        plt.show()        
    export_pdf.savefig(fig)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python saving multiple figures into one PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788685/python-saving-multiple-figures-into-one-pdf-file)

Answer (score 2):

OK, eventually i figured it out.
here is my solution:

```
with PdfPages(r'output_dist.pdf') as export_pdf:
    
    for col in df_f.columns:
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
        hist = df_f[col].hist(bins=10)
        print("Plotting for column {}".format(col))
        plt.title("{}".format(col), fontsize=20) 
        plt.show()
        
        export_pdf.savefig(fig)
```