# Converting email into PDF using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python so please accept my apology in advance if my question sounds stupids. I am writing a program in python which reads the email (.msg file) by using win32com.client and then write the email body message in PDF file. I am facing problem in writing into PDF format. I have been looking at different libraries (such as PyPDF2 and fpdf) for writing into PDF format. But the problem is both libraries talk about adding a line or a page in the PDF file. In my case email messages might be upto 5 or 6 pages long. So i am now stuck how to proceed further. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what problem you are having, are you getting an error when you try to create the pdf?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create PDF files in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252726/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-python)