# Create a pdf format file from Python

Tags: python, pdf

The following code generates a csv file in plain text format:

```
f = open('mytext.txt', 'wb')    
for row in hit_list:
    f.write(row)
f.close()
```

Now, I need to generate the same output but in pdf format, ie, mytext.pdf. Is this possible in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16632518/2319844

Comment: look into ReportLab

Comment: ReportLab worked fine for my purpose. Thanks.