# How to create pdf file from data from mongodb database in python?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pdf, flask

I am doing one web application in which user enters name and his comapany. So there are 5 company. In this application I want to generate pdf file for each company separately. Means if 20 users are entering data then pdf should generate company wise and there employee after clicking on generate PDF button.

I am using flask for this web application and cannot understand how to generate pdf from database. please if anyone knows the steps or good tutorial?

Comment: Inside your web application get the data from database, format it as per the requirement. Then use any compatible python library to generate the pdf (Google for python libraries which can be used with Flask for pdf generation).

Comment: [how to create pdf files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252726/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-python)

Comment: @anuragal ok i'll try it