# importing data in a template and creating PDFs in bulk

Tags: python, excel, powerbi

I have a file (datafile1) with more than 1.000 accounts followed by info in columns like this:

Accountname1 info1  info2  info3

Accountname2 info1  info2  info3
...

and I have a template in excel with some text and logos. I want to import the data from datafile1 to the template and create a individual PDF for all accounts. So let's say 1.000 pdfs. Is there any way to get this done? Maybe an out of the box program, or python code? Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library. You can read excel files and csv files with it, specifying a dialect argument.

```
import csv

with open(file_path)as excel_file:
    reader = csv.reader(excel_file, dialect='excel')
    for row in reader:
        #Your format goes here
```

You just have to specify what to do with each column in your file. In your case `row[0]` is account names and `row[N]` is infoN.

To write pdf's you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252726/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-python).