# Python - Pdf file with several figures in one page (not with subplots !!)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to produce a pdf file (with `PdfFile`) containing several figures in one page.

The most obvious solution is to use subplots. However, in my case this is not possible because each plot is produced by a different function. For example, there is a function `def plotPDF(inputData)` that will plot a probability distribution function (PDF), and another function `def plotCDF(inputData)` that will plot a cumulative distribution function (CDF). My code contains up to 20 different functions that will produce different plots when they are called.

What I want to do is to select some of these plots and produce a pdf file where they are contained in the same page. Following the example of PDF and CDF, I would like to produce a pdf file which contains one page where both plots are next to each other (in a similar way to the subplots).

I have tried to do this with subplots, but I cannot directly call the function within a subplot. That is, the following code wouldn't work:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plotPDF(inputData)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plotCDF(inputData)

plt.show()
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue ? I need to proceed like this because I need the plot functions to be independent for other purposes. Making subplots would mean changing this structure, and it would make the code less versatile.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Use the object oriented API, create a single figure and axes using `fig.add_subplot`  or `plt.subplot` and define your functions so they get the axes instance as argument.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to do what you are asking, maybe someone else will know...

*but*

the [recommended way](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#coding-styles) to write a plotting function is to pass a reference to an Axes object to the function, and write the function to use that axes to do the plotting.

so in your case:

```
def plotPDF(data, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca() # if no axes, use current axes
    plt.sca(ax) # set axes as current axes (important if you are using the pyplot API)
    # the rest of the function goes here

def plotCDF(data, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    plt.sca(ax)
    (...)


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
plotPDF(inputData, ax=ax1)
plotCDF(inputData, ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16632518/9718220) to a similar post? The answers in that post contain many ways to save an image into a pdf file, and only one (the matplotlib backend) requires subplots, as far as I know.

You can also save the files separately as png files, then use LaTeX / Word / another primitive way to arrange them into a pdf, which could be tedious.

Otherwise, could you maybe elaborate why using subplots wouldn't work with your functions? Maybe there is a way to use subplots, but then you'll need to show us the code.