# Combining all Elements with PyPDF2 (like one big image)

Tags: python, pypdf

I wrote Python code which creates music notation based on a user input. It generates a PDF and everything works fine.

The notation consists of 100's of small images. Is it possible to merge them all together into one big image?

I don't want them to be selectable or anything. Basically I want the PDF to be like one big picture per page.

Is that possible using PyPDF2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create PDF files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252726/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-python)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't. The PDF creation works perfectly fine. I just need a way to basically hide that it just consists of all these small images.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of what it looks like and maybe also your code?

Comment: Do you want to combine all of the small images to a single bigger image?