# Import XML to pre-generated PDF FORMS

Tags: python, xml, pdf

I am trying to import XML data into pre-fixed PDF form. The PDF forms are elaborate and have many named fields. An example of two named fields are "Consequence" and "Cause". So, for this example i will have an XML as following :

```
<multiple>
    <Causes> leak </Causes>
    <Consequences> fire and explosion </Consequences>
</multiple>
```

How do I do import this XML into specific PDF form fields programatically? I would prefer Python however I am okay if it is JavaScript

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  That is a very broad question, and likely to get closed.   What research have you done? e.g. Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252726/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-python

Comment: I have been researching this issue for a week and have looked at reportlab and xhtml2pdf and this import XML into a predefined PDF is unavaliable. I have managed to create pdfs and even pdf from xml using these. But what I am looking for is importing xml into PDF forms fields.(the pdf is already created in ADOBE  ACROBAT PRO with form fields)

Comment: I have been researching this issue for a week and have looked at reportlab and xhtml2pdf and this import XML into a predefined PDF is unavaliable. I have managed to create pdfs and even pdf from xml using these. But what I am looking for is importing xml into PDF forms fields.(the pdf is already created in ADOBE ACROBAT PRO with form fields) @Dijkgraaf sorry, it seems i forgot to tag you