# python packages to create Pdfs

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create pdf using python. The data that I have is dynamic and needs multiple pages. Matplotlib is good but it has some limitations. Can someone suggest any python packages to create the pdf?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create PDF files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2252726/6045800)

Answer (score 3):

you can use this  [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/)

for example:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
```

for learn more go to https://realpython.com/creating-modifying-pdf/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pdfme](https://github.com/aFelipeSP/pdfme). It's the most powerful library in python to create PDF documents.

You can check the docs [here](https://pdfme.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [PyFPDF](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf).
Check out the docs [here](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).