# Python One Page Report Based on Output of Function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, report

I am trying to prepare a report using Python. So the first function produces some output and next, I run function 2 and get an output, at the end, I need all output one below the other saved in .pdf or .doc format at one location, with some header/title to the report. It's a kind of one-pager report with multiple outputs, it can be pandas data frame or pictures.

```
# Function 1 Output
|Columns|Values|
|-------|------|
| A     | 100  |     
| B     | 200  |
| C     | 300  |
|-------|------|

# Some other processing steps.

# Function 2 Output
|Columns|Values|
|-------|------|
| D     | 400  |     
| E     | 500  |
| F     | 600  |
|-------|------|
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create PDF files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252726/how-to-create-pdf-files-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proposed script :**

All steps commented inside

```py
import pandas as pd
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


def function1():
    """Dataframe returned by function 1"""
    return pd.DataFrame({'Columns': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Values': [100, 200, 300]})


def function2():
    """Dataframe returned by function 2"""
    return pd.DataFrame({'Columns': ['D', 'E', 'F'], 'Values': [400, 500, 600]})


def create_report():
    """Creates PDF report"""
    # Create a new PDF document
    c = canvas.Canvas("report.pdf", pagesize=letter)

    # Set the title/header of the report
    c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 20) # sets Police
    c.drawString(50, 750, "Report Title")  # defines a title

    # Call function 1 and add its output to the report
    df1 = function1()
    c.setFont("Helvetica", 14) # sets Police
    c.drawString(50, 700, "Function 1 Output:") # Label for dataframe 1
    c.drawString(50, 680, str(df1)) # PDF printing

    # Add some spacing between function outputs
    c.drawString(50, 650, "-" * 50)

    # Call function 2 and add its output to the report
    df2 = function2()
    c.setFont("Helvetica", 14) # sets Police
    c.drawString(50, 620, "Function 2 Output:") # Label for dataframe 2
    c.drawString(50, 600, str(df2)) # PDF printing

    # Save the PDF document
    c.save()

create_report()
```

**Result :**

[image]

**To draw a plot in PDF**

Import :

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
```

In `create_report` function, for instance :

```py
...
    # Call function 1 and create a plot of its output
    df1 = function1()
    plt.figure(figsize=(5, 3)) # set plot size
    plt.bar(df1['Columns'], df1['Values']) # create bar plot
    plt.title('Function 1 Output') # set plot title
    plt.savefig('plot1.png') # save plot as image file

    # Add plot to PDF
    img = ImageReader('plot1.png')
    c.drawImage(img, 50, 700, width=300, height=300)
...
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Laurent B instead of str() can't we put pandas Database or matplot image?

Comment: Thanks for all your input, one more question related to space, is there any dynamic way to define position, for example if I have more rows lets say for second function, instead of "DEF" now if I get more variables let's say "DEFGHI" how can we auto adjuat and doesn't get into overlapping other text ? @Laurent B

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but to not overload page with several questions and add confusion, I suggest you close this question before opening a second one for the sake of readers. Otherwise we should have different matters not related with the main question on the same page. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
def df_to_text(df):
    text = df.to_string(index=False)
    return text + "\n\n"

df1_text = df_to_text(df1)
df2_text = df_to_text(df2)

doc = fitz.open()
page = doc.new_page()

page.insert_text((72, 72), text=f"Function 1 Output\n{df1_text}Function 2 Output\n{df2_text}")

doc.save('{path_to_save}'.pdf)
```

Here I have included the message and newlines to segregate the outputs based on function also  a side note, you can utilize blocks in fitz to style it asper need like segregating column names making it bold or different style varying the size of text.

For creating doc  use

> python-docx